# How to replace fancyhdr to a right scrbook way?

Tags: koma-script, fancyhdr

I've seen it is not right to use fancyhdr with scrbook, I've got a code with fancyhdr and I want to replace it to scrbook. This is my code:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{TEMA 13}
\rhead{\thepage }
\chead{Polinomios}
\rfoot{Oposiciones}
\rhead{\thepage }
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your document is `oneside`? Then you can use

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline,manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{TEMA 13}
\chead{Polinomios}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ofoot{Oposiciones}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

If your document is `twoside` there are two cases:

1. TEMA 13 should be on the left hand side on even pages and on the right hand side on odd pages? Then you can use the same code as for the `oneside` option because the `i` in `\ohead` means "inner".
2. TEMA 13 should be on the right hand side on both the even and the odd pages? Then you have to use `\lehead` and `\lohead` (`le` means left even, `lo` left odd).

Code for the second case:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline,manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{TEMA 13}\lohead{TEMA 13}
\chead{Polinomios}
\rehead{\pagemark}\rohead{\pagemark}
\lefoot{Oposiciones}\lofoot{Oposiciones}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are the changes if i use twoside?

Comment: @Tobal See my edited answer.